# PHP frameworks with AJAX scaffolding?

Tags: php, ajax, frameworks, scaffolding

Does someone know of any PHP frameworks which can create *scaffoldings* with AJAX?

Comment: If what you're asking is what I think you're asking, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only got one answer for you. It is [Yii Framework](http://yiiframework.com). After you do scaffolding in Yii, you will get data list page that use Ajax for searching, sorting, and paging.

Comment: Thank you bhoo-day, I'll take a look at it. It seems interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine that any would, especially as scaffolding should really only be used dev environments. They should never be rolled out as production back offices. (Unless the data is really really simple.)

Answer (score -1):

I know "Vue CRUD"

Vue crud use Vue front end

front end comunicate with backend with ajax tecnology

Vue.js based REST-ful CRUD system

Back end use php laravel

Is very easy code generator is very good

https://vue-crud.github.io/

Comment: is back end in laravel

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34462032)

Answer (score -1):

insert/update/delete in ajax only JavaScript feth
but custom files in folder stubs you can edit for add ajax edit form and list
laravel 10 php 8>

Open terminal

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app    
cd example-app    
composer require luiz0067yahoo/laravel-scaffold-command-1    
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=scaffold-stubs    
php artisan scaffold Category --fields=name:string,slug:string,parent_id:foreignId    
edit connection data base file .env    
php artisan key:generate    
php artisan migrate
```

Links

https://github.com/luiz0067yahoo/laravel-scaffold-command-1 https://packagist.org/packages/luiz0067yahoo/laravel-scaffold-command-1

Comment: Brian Tompsett - thanks very good